# How can I add only one record into a form in odoo

Tags: xml, treeview, odoo, formview

How can I add only one record into a form or treeview in odoo?
After adding the first record, create option should be disabled.

Comment: You can put a validation so they cant create more, but not disable the button

Comment: + you can also override the field_view_get and manipulate your view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I'll teach you :)

First you must make a record as follows:

```
<data noupdate="1">
    <record id="my_record_01" model="my.model">
        <field name="field_name">value</field>
    </record>
</data>
```

This will insert record in the database and noupdate means that this section wont change if you will update your module later. During development use 0 and after that set 1.

To disable write for tree view you can use

```
<tree create="false" delete="false">
</tree>
```

For form

```
<form edit="false" create="false" delete="false">
</form>
```

create="false" will disable(actually hide) create button, and at this time you can set edit="true" and record will be editable, delete="false" will disable delete option from 'more' dropdown
Note that tree has not attribute edit.
Also I recommend to create security rules security/ir.model.access.csv and set there write read delete and create rights

Comment: Can create the record from odoo interface?
Is ther a way to make create invisible in we have an instance in the databese?

Comment: You can make create invisible by tree and form option create=false as i mentioned my answer, also security/ir.model.access.csv make this securoty file and set create to zero

Comment: I forgot about security model. :D, Thank you !!